# Is $I+AA^T$ positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is real matrix, how can i show that $I+AA^T$ is positive definite matrix?

$I$ is the identity matrix and $A^T$ is a transpose of $A$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is because $$x^T(I+AA^T)x = x^Tx + (A^Tx)^T(A^Tx) = \Vert x \Vert_2^2 + \Vert A^Tx \Vert_2^2 \ge \Vert x \Vert_2^2> 0$$ where the last inequality is trivially true for any non-zero $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalues of $AA^T$. This means that:

$$\det\left[\lambda I - AA^T\right] = 0$$

$AA^T$ has all its eigenvalues greater or equal to $0$ ($\lambda \geq 0$).

Let $\gamma$ be the eigenvalues of $I + AA^T$. Then:

$$\det\left[\gamma I - (I + AA^T)\right] = \det\left[(\gamma - 1)I - AA^T)\right] = 0$$

If you pose $\lambda = \gamma - 1$, then $\gamma = \lambda + 1$, and hence $\gamma > 0$.
You can conclude that $I+AA^T$ is definite positive.

Comment: Though your approach can be used, your answer as such is incomplete. All the eigenvalues being positive doesn't imply that the matrix is positive definite unless it is symmetric. (though the converse, i.e., positive definite implies positive eigenvalues is true). For instance, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1& -5\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ has positive eigenvalues but the matrix is not positive definite. Hence, you also need to mention that the matrix is symmetric. Also, this way of proving is slightly a round about way. Mine follows directly from the definition.